# How to save each loop of a python function to a separate file?

Tags: python

I have a question regarding a small Python program I would like to finish. I learned about coding, but this is my first real program.

With this program I want to combine 2 textfiles and insert a privnote link in between of those 2 files. In the end I want to save this combined file to a new output file. This function should be looped for a pre defined amount of times and each loop should be saved in a separate file:

This is my code:

```
import pyPrivnote as pn
import sys

def Text():
    Teil_1  = open("Teil_1.txt", "r")
    Content_1 = Teil_1.read()
    print(Content_1)

    note_link = pn.create_note("Data")
    print(note_link)

    Teil_2  = open("Teil_2.txt", "r")
    Content_2 = Teil_2.read()
    print(Content_2)
```

---

Above part works. Next part is where I struggle.

```
i = 0 + 1
while i <= 3:
    filename = "C:\\Users\\Python\\Datei%d.txt" % i
    f = open(filename, "r")
    Text()
    f.close()
```

How can I save each loop output of the Text() function to a new file?

I would like to save it the output to the relative path /output/ and the files should have the name "file01, file02...".

I searched for several hours now, but I don´t find an answer to this problem.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you add input / ouput examples ?

Comment: @PythonBeginner1337 you are missing `i+=1` after `f.close()`. This may make it loop forever and never write to another file

Answer (score 0):

Pass the file to `Text()`:

```
def Text(out_file):
    Teil_1  = open("Teil_1.txt", "r")
    Content_1 = Teil_1.read()
    out_file.write(Content_1)
    Teil_1.close()

    note_link = pn.create_note("Data")
    out_file.write(note_link)

    Teil_2  = open("Teil_2.txt", "r")
    Content_2 = Teil_2.read()
    out_file.write(Content_2)
    Teil_2.close()
```

And:

```
i = 1
while i <= 3:
    filename = "C:\\Users\\Python\\Datei%d.txt" % i
    i += 1
    f = open(filename, "rw")
    Text(f)
    f.close()
```

But inside the loop you are opening 2 files. There are easier ways to achieve this if you want to write the content of these files in one single file.

Comment: How can I do this? I edited my code and I can limit the amount of combined text files now inside of the shell, but still I don´t save this output to the files in my directory.

Comment: Oh!, I see. The output file is opened in read mode, I did not see this. I will update my answer. (change `'r'` to `'w'` in the `open` mehtod)

Comment: well, @Billy Ferguson noticed this before me. Thanks!

Comment: Now it is working. Thank you very much for your help.